# Comparing different groups performance over time

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, time-varying-covariate

Let's say I am trying to compare the performance of a group of salesmen over the course of three years (not all have three full years of data).  I have monthly data showing the number of customers, number of sales, and revenue for each.  What I want to do is analyze these to see which salesmen are statistically outperforming or under performing the group.

The first thing I thought of was doing a t-test comparing each salesman to the average but I don't think that would work due to the time aspect.  Is there a specific type of test/modeling technique I should look into?

Answer (score 1):

To test for salesman within a group I would for each characteristic (# of cust, #of sales ,revenue) construct an ARIMA model that might include trends/level shifts,seasonal structure) while identifying potential anomalies. I would do this for each salesman in the group. I would then determine a common model by examining each of the models for similar structure. I would then estimate this model for each of the salesman separately and for the group as a whole. I would then construct an F test to test the hypothesis of a common set of parameters across salesman by pooling the error sos from each salesman vis-a-vis the error sos for the group composite series in the standard way.

If you have K groups with say Nk salesman in each group , then I would use the suggested procedure at that level rather than at the salesman within a group example I presented in the first paragraph..